# \bbl@main@language error in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors, biber

Here is a simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  backend      = biber,
  bibstyle     = biblatex-sp-unified,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

Which refers to [this `bbx`](https://github.com/semprag/biblatex-sp-unified/blob/master/bbx/biblatex-sp-unified.bbx) and this simple `bib` file:

```
@article{test,
  Author = {test},
  Title = {test}
}
```

This used to work. After updating my MacTeX distribution this Sunday morning and (full disclosure) doing a `sudo tlmgr update --all`, I now receive errors like the following:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \bbl@main@language

l.12 \printbibliography{
                        }
?
```

Curiously, if either the `Author` or `Title` field is missing, I don't get an error. Moreover, if I remove the `bibstyle` option, the error goes away. This leads me to suspect that the problem is somewhere in the `bbx` file linked above, but that's as far as my limited knowledge and expertise gets me.

I realize this might be a rather specific question (and I have opened an issue on the github I linked to), but perhaps there is a general issue causing the problem here, in which case others might benefit from a general solution.

Comment: Did you remove all of your auxiliary files? There has been a Biber update and it's possible that some `.bbl` files might thus need to be regenerated.

Comment: Yes. I created this MWE from scratch to try to pin down the problem.

Comment: That's a non-standard `.bbx`: probably it's in need of an update

Comment: No doubt -- I thought it might be edifying to know what's going wrong here.

Comment: Does loading `babel` (with a language option) help?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you! Any idea why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> This problem was fixed in version 3.5 of `biblatex`. An update to the current version of `biblatex` should solve the issue.
>
> Note that a similar problem could occur with ancient versions of `babel` or `polyglossia`, in which case the solution is again to update these packages.

The culprit is the line

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,thesis,incollection,unpublished,inproceedings]{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}%
```

`\MakeSentenceCase*` checks for the document language as saved in `\bbl@main@language`, since you load neither `babel` nor `polyglossia`, no such command is available and `biblatex` complains.

The problem has been addressed in the dev version and a fix will be included in the upcoming version 3.5 of `biblatex` (see the discussion from 2016-06-19 on [issue #393](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/393)).

Of course the issue is not restricted to your special `.bbx` file - all code that uses `\MakeSentenceCase*` is affected. `biblatex-ieee` uses a special format for titles which calls that macro and so is also affected, even though you won't find a direct call for `\MakeSentenceCase*` in its `\DeclareFieldFormat` commands.

---

Solution one is to load `babel` or `polyglossia` with the correct language option (`american` or `british` for `babel`), this is especially recommended if you don't write in English.

If you don't want to load either of the packages, you can use the language-unaware unstarred version **note that the starred version of `\MakeSentenceCase*` is normally *strongly* preferred because it obeys the language settings, so using the unstarred version can only be a temporary work-around**

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,thesis,incollection,unpublished,inproceedings]{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}%
```

or get rid of sentence case for good with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,thesis,incollection,unpublished,inproceedings]{titlecase}{#1}%
```

Comment: This could be considered a bug in `biblatex`, I believe since `babel`/`polyglossia` are strongly recommended, but not required.

Comment: Thank you! That is super helpful. I am somewhat curious why this wasn't exposed until I updated my TeX distribution, but that'd just be gravy.

Comment: @SimonC Checking for the document language was only implemented in version 3.4 of `biblatex` (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/393). You will only have gotten up to version 3.3 in TeX live 2015. But 2016 ships with 3.4

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/FKahkrwlS4Q/Q6bJgcCjDAAJ from this morning.