# Grouping citations with bibtex, ieeetr style

Tags: bibtex, ieee-style

I am using `bibtex`, with the bibliography style `ieeetr` to create my references. I have read the IEEE style manual, and I know that I should leave citations in separate sets of brackets, e.g., `[3], [4]`.

However, I know that they should be hyphenated when consecutive, in groups of 3 or more, e.g., `[5]-[10]` but the `ieetr` style doesn't seem to do this automatically. Any ideas? I have already tried using the `cite` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{cite} 
\begin{document} 
This is my text, and here are some citations \cite{article1}, \cite{article2}, \cite{article3}.
\bibliography{examplebib} 
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} 
\end{document}
```

And the bib file "examplebib.bib"

```
@article{article1,
  author    = {Doe, John},
  title     = {Title of article},
  journal   = {journal of article},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {11},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {11--13},
  publisher = {Journal Publisher},
}
@article{article2,
  author    = {Doe, John},
  title     = {Title of article},
  journal   = {journal of article},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {11},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {11--13},
  publisher = {Journal Publisher},
}
@article{article3,
  author    = {Doe, John},
  title     = {Title of article},
  journal   = {journal of article},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {11},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {11--13},
  publisher = {Journal Publisher},
}
```

Comment: Are you writing this document to be published in a journal? If so, their staff will take care of details like this. Does it have to be IEEE style? I just looked up my recent works and revtex seems to do this automatically.

Comment: No, I'm not writing for a journal. It does have to IEEE. I don't know much about revtex. Is there a revtex version for IEEE?

Answer (score 2):

An approximation to this cite style can be achieved using the `natbib` package:

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{square,citesep={],[}}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
```

Then you can use `\cite{article1,article3}` to get `[1],[3]`. However, any consecutive range like `\cite{article1,article2,article3}` still gives `[1-3]`. This behavior is hard-coded and cannot be changed without redefining the `\cite` command.

Another option is the `biblatex` and `biblatex-ieee` packages (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315537/6372) for why `babel` is needed):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{examplebib.bib}

\begin{document}
This is my text, and here are some citations \cite{article1,article2,article3}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This gives the correct formatting when you use version 1.2d of the `biblatex-ieee` package (from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee)). The compression doesn't work with 1.1n, which is the version my TeXLive distribution provides.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was hoping there was a way to do it without biblatex. The Natbib solution you point out changes more in my document than I wanted.